# How to have an image automatically scale (not using breakpoints)

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox and there's a row on my site where a text block should take up roughly the left 40% of the screen, and the image should take up the right 60%. However, I'd like the image to shrink faster than the text when the browser image is resized.

Flex-shrink did not appear to have any effect when using an  in that place, the image appeared to be of a fixed size. I tried switching to a  with a background-image property set, but since there is nothing inside the div, the image isn't visible. I can hard-code widths and heights but that defeats the purpose of having the image scale.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying giving the image a max-width of 100% and set the height to auto. As such it will always scale to fit the size of the parent.

```
img{
    max-width :100%;
    height:auto;
}
```